# Use python to call a batch script that sets env variables and run another program that uses them

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, subprocess

I need to call a batch script from Python that sets environment variables and then use those environment variables to complete the execution of other programs. I am in a windows environment running python.

I cannot call `Popen("setupEnv.bat")` and then call `Popen("command args")` because the env variables are lost after the batch script is finished. Since this failed, I am trying to open a cmd prompt manually and intercept the output of each command separately, but I'm having trouble with this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe",stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
               stderr=subprocess.STD  OUT,shell=True)
stdin.write("setupEnv.bat")
stdin.write("command args")
```

I need to intercept the output for these seperately. Is there some mechanism to pause the childprocess or wait for its output. `proc.communicate()` and `proc.wait()` both wait for the child process to terminate. I need to send two separate inputs to a process and log the response for each.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This may not be exactly what you're looking for**
You could get the value of the var's then store them in a file.
After that get the contents of the text file with the other program/language. Just do that :)
Hopefully that answered your question!